# Can abruptly turning the main power switch to a heat pump off while running in cool mode damage the unit?

Tags: electrical, pump, heat, circuit

My heat pump was running on `Cool` for air conditioning when the power valve outside was switched off. The fan kept running but the cooling element wasn’t working.

I noticed the problem when the temperature inside reached 80 degrees F. while set to 70 degrees F. Is turning off the main power switch a concern for the unit breaking or malfunctioning in the future?

Comment: Interesting. In my installation everything is powered from a single source, and I believe pulling the outside switch removes power from the whole system.

Comment: @keshlam, its supposed to turn off everything, as a safety feature.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience turning off a compressor while it is running does not cause damage. What can cause damage is to immediately turn it back on before the pressure on the high side has had a chance to decline to the normal starting pressure.

Comment: This, and it was a problem with older units that could require you to power cycle them. At this point any unit like that should be really old though, as all the modern stuff I've seen has a 'hot start' delay circuit built in.

Comment: Nearly all modern HPs (like less than 20 yo) have built in sensors that will delay turning it back on for about 5 minutes after power is restored.  Even the tstats on mine have a "WAIT" on their displays that remains until it's safe to power up the outdoor unit.